# How to map complex object attribute using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way in SQLAlchemy to perform some kind of 'deep mapping' of the class attributes?

For instance: `obj.attr.nested_attr`, I'd like to tell `obj` mapper how to directly map `nested_attr` to a `nested_attr` column in a table.

Python: 3.10.7

SQLAlchemy: 1.4.41

Let's say we have domain model of:

```
@dataclass
class FullName:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str


@dataclass
class User:
    name: FullName
    date_of_birth: datetime
    etc...
```

And an SQLAlchemy table model like:

```
users = sqlalchemy.Table(
   "users",
   metadata,
   sqlalchemy.Column("first_name", sqlalchemy.String),
   sqlalchemy.Column("last_name", sqlalchemy.String),
   etc...
)
```

Is there any way in SQLAlchemy to map `name` (which is of type `FullName`) attributes `first_name` and `last_name` to `users` table columns `first_name` and `last_name`?

I tried:

```
mapper_registry = registry()

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        User,
        users,
        properties={
            "name.first_name": users.c.first_name,
            "name.last_name": users.c.last_name,
        },
    )
```

However, SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to comprehend accessing attributes' of an attribute by dot notation.

Is there any other way to directly map `user.name.first_name` to `first_name` column of the `users` table?

Answer (score 0):

[Composite](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/composites.html) may be the solution you are looking for.